# How can I get the texture that came with this model?

Tags: texturing, uv

I opened this blender file (https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-blend-model-centaur-centauress-pink/703314) and exported it to FBX, but there was no texture. I can only see the model with the texture in the "model view". Do I have to unwrap the texture? I'm trying to get the texture apart from the model. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share screen shot of your node view ?

Comment: I don't know how to open node view

Comment: Please take a look of steps below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Answer (score 1):

I had to bake the Vertex paint to the UV texture and then I exported the **UV map** as a .PNG file and it has textures now!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The texture is stored in the vertex color. To use it in cycles you need to add an attribute node, you can find in the the add menu Vertex Color -> Col.

Pluging the color output of the attribute node in the color input of the diffuse you get the the texture.

[image: Shader for accessing the vector colors]